# Helmholtz Free Energy minimization during an irreversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

Consider the classical $(N,V,T)$ system, and its Helmholtz free energy (HFE) $A=U-TS_{system}$.
The system is placed in contact with an hotter heath bath.

It is said that, at equilibrium, the HFE of the system reaches a minimum, i.e. $dU - TdS_{system} = 0$. But, for an irreversible heat transfer $dQ$ from the heat bath to the system, we end up with $dQ=dU<TdS_{system}$. So when does the equilibrium get realized? Do we need an "extra" transfer of heat to the system?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly you seem to be trying to irreversibly transfer heat between 2 body at the same temperature, but the zeroth law tells you that there is no heat transfer between bodies at the same temperature *by definition*. This is why we do the entire dance with infinitesimal changes in the reversible case.

Comment: Not really...as I have said, the heat bath is hotter (and way bigger) than the system. A small loss of heat (approximately) does not alter its temperature, which we could consider constant.

Comment: Then you are missing a $dT$ term as in GClavier's answer. I missed the part about it being hotter and assumed you were using equilibrium with the the heat bath to fix $dT=0$

Comment: Thank you. What I however still don't understand is that if equilibrium means $dF=0$, so for an irreversible process ($dU-TdS<0$), $-SdT>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your differential form is incomplete.

Actually: $$dF=dU -SdT-TdS =-SdT$$

Equilibrium is reached when $dF=0$, so when $-SdT=0$, meaning the temperature constant over time ($T_{system}=T_{bath}$).

That's why at constant temperature Helmoltz free energy is the minimum potential. In the same way regarding a constant pressure process the enthalpy is given by: $$H=U-PV$$

Because it's differential form is then $dH=dU+VdP+PdV=VdP$. At equilibrium with a pressure bath, enthalpy do not vary and is in a minimum.

Each of these is obtained by a Lagrange multiplier meaning that for a constraint on an intensive parameter $X$ coupled to an extensive parameter $Y$ such as $\frac{dU}{dY}=X$ you can construct Z the thermodynamic potential associated like:
$$Z=U-XY$$
Such as its differential form vanishes at equilibrium.

I hope this helps, a bit, the underlying physics is better understood with solid math background in my opinion.

**edit**: I made a little mistake, the first formula is only valid at constant volume as my differential is $dF=-PdV-SdT$ in  the general case. In any case at equilibrium the volume of the system is supposed constant and no irreversible work is involved. The same reasoning apply as for the internal energy at equilibrium of a closed system.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, in an irreversible process, as I wrote, we end up with $dU-TdS <0$...so does it mean that $-SdT>0$?

Comment: Well actually equilibrium is realised when dT=0, that means that the flux of heat from the system to the bath is compensated by a flux of heat from the bath to the system. The temperature of your system can increase or decrease and the entropy will vary accordingly but don't forget that the entropy of the bath may change too, so the overall entropy variation goes to zero at equilibrium, as heat fluxes compensate.

Comment: This is clarifying,  thank you. I have to admit that in every text I've looked, this answer simply doesn't appear :-(

Comment: Last but not least, heat and work are not state function with clean differential forms as you can reach the same energy state with different path regarding a plane were coordinates are the heat and work received. They are just small variation of the energy. Write them with \delta in Latex such as $\delta Q$ and $\delta W$. ;) It's a wrong abuse to write them $d...$.

Glad to help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I still don't get it...if an irreversible process stops when $dT=0$ (no net flux of heat between the system and the heat bath), so does it mean that $dF<0$? Or that the changes that happen to the system's and heat bath's U, S and T bring to an equilibrium point where $dF=0$?

Comment: If no work exchange is performed during the process, yes. In the other case you can show that $dF\leq W$ where W is the work you took from the system. If this work is zero (no volume change), $dF \leq 0$ meaning that the free energy has decreased. At equilibrium, the free energy is in at a minimum value.